# Is there an environment variable like PRINTER but for a remote server?

Tags: printing

I've had to uninstall `cupsd` and `cups-browserd` because I couldn't print to a remote printer when they were running (and gave up after 3 hours).

Printing works great now from applications, but from the CLI I have to do things like this:

```
enscript -p- reasons_i_love_linux.md | lpr -H server:631
```

I'd like to be able to just say:

```
enscript reasons_i_love_linux.md
```

like in the old days before I "upgraded" CUPS.

This turns out to be hard to find via Google...

Again, the cups daemon is *not* running on this machine, only on the remote printer server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should CUPS not be duly setup with the remote printer settings in your local device so you can just run that command?

Comment: Do you mean CUPS on the local machine? Does my first line answer that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have (at least) the "client" parts of CUPS installed. Then put this line into a file saved as `/etc/cups/client.conf` (for system-wide usage) or into `${HOME}/.cups/client.conf` (if you want to use different remote CUPS servers for different users):

```
ServerName servername:631
```

or

```
ServerName server-ip-address:631
```

Note that `/etc/cups/client.conf` must be world-readable since it's user-space applications that will be reading it (not a root-owned daemon).

Should the remote CUPS server be rather new, you have to tell your print client to ask the remote server to use IPP v1.1 (not v2.0 as the newer CUPS versions do):

```
ServerName servername:631/version=1.1
```

Now your local `cupsd` will be by-passed (if it's running at all), or no attempt to contact it will be made (if it's not running). The printing client programs will directly talk to the remote CUPS first (not the one located on `localhost:631`, as they otherwise would without the presence of the `client.conf` entry outlined above).

To answer your question about an environment variable: Yes, there is one. It is called `CUPS_SERVER`. You could use it on a case-by-case base whenever you print a job if the `client.conf` entry is not there, or if you want to override the remote server named in `client.conf`, or if it listens on a non-standard port

```
CUPS_SERVER=other_server:631 lp -p printername jobfile
```

You can also use it to list the names and status of (shared) printers on a remote server:

```
CUPS_SERVER=other_server:631             lpstat -p
CUPS_SERVER=other_server:631/version=1.1 lpstat -p

CUPS_SERVER=other_server:631             lpstat -v
CUPS_SERVER=other_server:631/version=1.1 lpstat -v
```